# Using pre_get_posts to filter by custom fields while using static front page

Tags: homepage, pre-get-posts, customization

I'm trying to filter a custom post type loop by several custom fields using pre_get_posts.
 Category pages display just fine. I'm having trouble with the static front page which for some reason displays the blog posts template (with custom post type posts) instead of the custom page template I set as static front page. Hope someone can shed some light on this.

Here's the code ...

```
function filter_posts( $query ) {
    if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        if ( get_query_var('paged') ) { $paged = get_query_var('paged'); }
    elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) { $paged = get_query_var('page'); }
    else { $paged = 1; }
        $today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 

        $metaquery = array(
                        array(
                                             'key' => 'expire_date',
                             'value' => $today,
                                 'type' => 'DATETIME',
                                 'compare' => '>'
                        ),

                        array(
                                             'key' => 'sold',
                             'value' => 'yes',
                                 'type' => 'string',
                                 'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
                        )
                );

        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'cpt' ) );
        $query->set( 'meta_query', $metaquery );
        $query->set('page_id', ''); //Empty
            $query->set( 'post_status', 'publish' );
        $query->set( 'paged', $paged );
        $query->is_page = 0;
            $query->is_singular = 0;

    }

    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'filter_posts',11 );
```

Comment: you've altered the query, so you've changed the path WordPress will follow through the hierarchy to select the template that belongs to that query. I've found it easier to just create a new query in the template for additional content rather than try to make a singular page query into a query for another post type.

Comment: How can I help WordPress find that static template again? I don't want to edit that template because I may turn this into a plugin later on.